# Is there a way to assign values to an Option Base 1 array in VBA using a single line?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am assigning integers (11 in total) to an array with index 1 to 11, one index at a time.

Is there a way to do it in one line, similar to how it is done for example in Matlab.

How I am doing it now:

```
Dim cols(1 To 11) As Integer

cols(1) = 2
cols(2) = 3
cols(3) = 5
cols(4) = 6
cols(5) = 7
cols(6) = 9
cols(7) = 10
cols(8) = 13
cols(9) = 14
cols(10) = 15
cols(11) = 16
```

How I would like to do it:

```
Dim cols(1 To 11) As Integer

cols = [2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16]
```

I am aware that it can be done without defining the variable as an array, but that returns the array with index 0 to 10:

```
Dim cols As Variant

cols = Array(2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16]
```

Comment: a `For` loop ? 3 lines

Comment: You could add `Option Base 1` to the top of the module - your last example will work on 1 to 11 then.  Or go with Shai's suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a Variant array is OK:

```
Dim cols()
cols = [{2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16}]
```

Comment: Clarification: This is syntactic sugar for `cols = Application.Evaluate("{2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16}")` which evaluates a string as an Excel formula.

Comment: Well, `[]` and `Evaluate` are not exactly the same, but close enough for most purposes.

Comment: A Variant array is more than OK. It solved my problem in this case, but what if I need to index to be 2 To 12  or 7 to 17 ?

Anyway, your answer helped me, and I marked it as accepted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then you'd have to loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with two lines instead of one line, you can try this:

```
Dim cols As Variant

cols = Array(2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16)
ReDim Preserve cols(1 To UBound(cols) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rory has the right answer, but we can get the code to visually look like it's on one line like this:

```
Dim cols(): cols = [{2,3,5,6,7,9,10,13,14,15,16}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating each number you can evaluate the row() function (if you aren't disposing yet of the `SEQUENCE()` function available in version 2019/365 *):

```
Dim cols: cols = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(2:16)"))
' cosmetic
ReDim Preserve cols(0 To UBound(cols) - 1)
```

Note: ReDim only if you want to get a zero based 1-dim array.

**Hints to version MS Excel 365**
*) the dynamic `SEQUENCE()` function can be applied immediately as formula on top of a vertical area, e.g. `=SEQUENCE(15;1;2)`; integration into a VBA code to get a "flat" 1-dim array would result in

`Dim cols: cols = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("SEQUENCE(15;1;2)"))`