# Looping through specific columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I know we can loop through columns in VBA by doing this:
`For j = 3 To 6` but I want to loop through specific columns only, say `For j = 3, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9 to 12` but this does not seem workable. Does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this outcome? Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

The code for the workbook, I changed the part where to Mikku's suggestion to loop through the columns. So I changed it to this:

```
Private Function MissingEntries() As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
Dim atLeastOneLine As Boolean

atLeastOneLine = False
For i = 12 To 21
    If (Cells(i, 2) <> "") Then
        atLeastOneLine = True

Dim k As Integer
Dim cols()
cols = [{3, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 10,12,13}]
For k = LBound(cols) To UBound(cols)
If Cells(i, cols(k)) = "" Then

    'For j = 3 To 5
        'If Cells(i, j) = "" Then

 MsgBox ("Please supply values for highlighted cells")
            MissingEntries = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    If WrongSerialNumber(i) Then
        MissingEntries = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    End If
    Next
If Not atLeastOneLine Then
MsgBox ("Please supply values for at least one line")
MissingEntries = True
Else
MissingEntries = False
End If

End Function
```

Rather than the ones written as comments. I'm not sure what is wrong because the rows and cols range seem correct....but the msgBox still pops up: "Please supply values for highlighted cells". Even though all the cells needed to be filled were already filled. Essentially, those columns that I need them to be filled are the ones with red font. 
See how all the columns I need to be filled are already filled but there's still this error message:

[image]

Comment: Save the numbers in a Array, and loop through it.

Comment: @Mikku hello Mikku, i saw this somewhere:
`CN = Array("1","2","3","5","6","7","9","11","13","14","15")`
`For column = LBound(CN) To UBound(CN)`
Somthing like this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim cols()
cols = [{3, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 12}]


For i = LBound(cols) To UBound(cols)

    Debug.Print Cells(1, cols(i))

Next
```

Help taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510246/5720144)

---

**Update:**

`If Cells(i, k) = "" Then` In this line you are using `k` which is running from 1 to the number of elements in your array. Rather you should be using `If Cells(i, cols(k)) = "" Then` which will refer to the kth element of your array, that is what you need to check.

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim cols()
cols = [{3, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 10,12,13}]
For k = LBound(cols) To UBound(cols)
If Cells(i, cols(k)) = "" Then

        'For j = 3 To 5
            'If Cells(i, j) = "" Then

 MsgBox ("Please supply values for highlighted cells")
                MissingEntries = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        If WrongSerialNumber(i) Then
            MissingEntries = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
 Next 
 If Not atLeastOneLine Then
    MsgBox ("Please supply values for at least one line")
    MissingEntries = True
Else
    MissingEntries = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: SORRY MIKKU I re-arranged the data validation list so the file is no longer corrupted. Now I'm not sure if the code has an error due to my row or column. Please see my updated post!

Comment: @psyduck .. I added an explanation in the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes.. I explained it in the Update. Here Again for you *If Cells(i, k) = "" Then In this line you are using k which is running from 1 to the number of elements in your array. Rather you should be using If Cells(i, cols(k)) = "" Then which will refer to the kth element of your array* @psyduck

Comment: oh!! So sorry I'm blind....ah....I didnt know that I had to include the col() in with the k..when i ran your code it says "end if without if" so I deleted the end if after exit function but right now it says "Next without for"

Comment: @psyduck .. The main question was how to loop the col numbers. That I showed you how. Your code however have certain other problems, which are unrelated to the question and which I can't solve unless I know the context of what you are trying to do. I just corrected the part where you were confused, your code is as it is otherwise. :)

Comment: ah..ok..I ran the code and this time it says "Run-time error 1004" "Application-defined or object-defined error". Then it highlights "If Cells(i, cols(k)) = "" Then" line

Comment: That's because you have not defined `i`. What is `i` @psyduck ?

Comment: I defined i as integer, see my updated code above !

Comment: @psyduck ... yes that's correct. Now look where you have assigned any value to `i` ?

Comment: oooops...i get what you mean now..but i'm still running iinto the same error sigh..oh same error as in it throws up the msgbox "Please supply value for highlighted cells" even tho all cells necessary are filled

Comment: oh actually i think its working now..let me confirm again and get back to you!!

Comment: No @psyduck .. I can't answer multiple questions in one question. If its working for you then accept the answer and ask a new question on the other issue. All the Best Mate :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198189/discussion-between-mikku-and-psyduck).

Answer (score 1):

I like @Mikku's answer as it gives you a bit more of a clear view which columnnumbers are included, it just seems more suited for your question. However I would like to show you that you could skip the `.Evaluate` and assign a non-contigueous range like so:

```
Sub Test()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each col In .Range("C:C,E:I,L:L").Columns
        Debug.Print col.Column
    Next col
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, this looks interesting too, I didn't know this could be done. Hm..I will consider implementing it, but currently I'm not too sure if my row or column is the reason for my error Msgbox. Please see my updated post!

Comment: Have you made some sort of function? What's the value of 'i'

Comment: Yes, so sorry for the incomplete code. Would it help if you could view the workbook here? [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-duHhGVa6Q4a6y_bwQ74gWm6sz_vzC5s)

Comment: You better explain in your main question what's going on. I have seen the workbook and it seems you are trying to loop through row 12-21 with i variable. I cant see those rows filled out. Also, why do you have a function instead of a macro. What cell do you use this in? And with what goal? Answer all those questions and update your post if you want to be able to be helped out.

Comment: If the users fill in the serial ID column in col B (it doesn't have to be all 10 of them, as long as one is filled), they need to fill up the other columns that have red font. Hence, if col B is filled up but any of the cells with red fonts are not filled up, I want the error message to pop up. The variable i is to indicate the number if rows it should be looping through. It works only for the first row but for subsequent rows it will throw up the msgbox error