# Loop through columns in an array with scpecified column numbers

Tags: vba

I have a problem with looping through each column in an array, and the error that I get is:

> Variable is not defined.

The idea is similar to the one highlighted in this question: [Looping through specific columns with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550086/looping-through-specific-columns-with-vba)
At the same time, I have exactly the same loop in a different worksheet that works just fine. So I cannot detect what is really causing the issue.

I have tried changing my loop to one suggested in the similar question, yet the problem with "cols" persists.

**My code:**

```
columnsConvert = Array(15, 16, 17, 19, 21)  
    For k = fRow To lRow
        For Each col In columnsConvert
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(k, col).Value) = True Then
                    .Cells(k, col).Value = .Cells(k, col).Value / xrate
                End If
            End With
        Next col
    Next k
```

**Changed code:**

```
columnsConvert = Array(15, 16, 17, 19, 21)
    For k = fRow To lRow
        For j = LBound(columnsConvert) To UBound(columnsConvert)
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(k, cols(j)).Value) = True Then
                    .Cells(k, cols(j)).Value = .Cells(k, cols(j)).Value / xrate
                End If
            End With
        Next j
    Next k
```

It would be great if someone could identify what the issue is or suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: Use `columnsConvert(j)` should work? Reason is the original code foreach-loops items in an array. Your new code for-loops index 0..n numbers.

Comment: @Whome, actually that makes complete sense! Thanks a ton, I just implemented it and it works.